# API DocuSign SOAP CreateEnvelope RouterOrder missing

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I'm creating a Recipient with this code

```
Recipient DocuSign_recipient = new Recipient();
DocuSign_recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
DocuSign_recipient.Email = contact.EMailAddress1;
DocuSign_recipient.UserName = string.Format("{0} {1}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName);
DocuSign_recipient.Type = RecipientType;
```

but the API Service doesn't receive the RoutingOrder.
API DocuSign receive this

```
<Recipient>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <UserName>Olivier Roecker</UserName>
    <Email>olivier.roecker@toto.gov</Email>
    <Type>Signer</Type>
</Recipient>
```

Someone has already meet this case ?
Best regards

Comment: I have written the same function in REST and all is right, it's a workaround but the problem is not resolved with a SOAP call.

Comment: Are you using docusign/docusign-soap-sdk? If so, what language? Recipient.RoutingOrder is correct for the API, the SDK may be missing the functionality.

Comment: After a quick GIT SDK code search, I see the functionality being used in code snippets in PHP, C#, APEX but not Java.

Comment: The language is C#, the RoutingOrder is accepted, because it is described in the WSDL manifest but nothing is send to the DocuSign API Server.

Comment: Just posted a solution, please review and accept if that works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `RoutingOrder` is one of the SOAP properties you need to include an extra flag for.  I've seen this before on a couple of other properties such as custom tab for instance, not sure why it's ever needed, but to specify a routing order on the recipient try using this code:

```
DocuSign_recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
DocuSign_recipient.RoutingOrderSpecified = true;
```

It's that second line that you are missing, on some properties this needs to be specified.  Give that a try, it should resolve your issue and get the property into the request.

---

For reference here's where I found this:  https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/blob/master/MS.NET/CodeSnippets/CodeSnippets/CodeSnippets.cs